# Bootstrap search box with select and clear icon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want large search box with select options and clear buttons in bootstrap 3+ .I tried below code , but its not aligning properly.

```
<form role="form">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="input-group">
         <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
         <select class="input-group-addon selectpicker">
            <option>Mustard</option>
            <option>Ketchup</option>
            <option>Relish</option>
         </select>
         <input Placeholder="Search Food" type="text" class="form-control input-lg hasclear">
         <span class="clearer input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Demo : http://dietbook.xyz/

Comment: Could you be a little more specific about how it should look, isn't that clear based on your link.

Comment: I need a dropdown something like http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ like this beside search box

Comment: select box like this ...http://i.stack.imgur.com/eGjIS.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This is you want?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Action <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!-- /btn-group -->
      <input type="text" class="form-control"> <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
```

Comment: replace this col-lg-6 with col-lg-12 in second line.

Comment: clearbox is not working and select box is not selecting the item ?